# Add a variable to a column in a CSV file

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have a large file (~10GB) and I want to duplicate that file 10 times but each time add a variable to the first column:

```
for i in (1, 10):
    var = (i-1) * 1000
    # add var to the first column of the file and save the file as file(i).csv
```

So far I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
   t=1
   j=$(( $i - t ))
   s=1000
   person_id=$(( j * add ))
   awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{$1=$1+$person_id} {print $0}' file.csv > file$i.csv
done
```

but no change in column value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk variables are different from shell variables.

Replace:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{$1=$1+$person_id} {print $0}' file.csv > file$i.csv
```

With:

```
awk -F"," -v id="$person_id" 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{$1=$1+id} {print $0}' file.csv > "file$i.csv"
```

This uses the `-v` option to define an awk variable `id` whose value is the value of the shell variable `person_id`.

Because `,` is not a shell-active character, the code can be simplified.  Also, changing the location of the definition of `OFS` can further shorten the code:

```
awk -F, -v id="$person_id" 'NR>1{$1+=id} 1' OFS=, file.csv > "file$i.csv"
```

Lastly, we replaced `{print $0}` with the cryptic shorthand `1`.  (This works because awk interprets `1` as a logical condition which it evaluates to true and, since no action was supplied, awk will perform the default action which is to print the line.)

Comment: Thank you so much!